# Can I put the SD card from my Pi3 into a new Pi4?

Tags: pi-4, pi-3b+, raspberry-pi-os

I have a Pi 3B+ from some years ago, and recently (2 days ago) I completely formatted it and installed new version of RaspberryPi OS, I was using Piwigo to have a family photo gallery but it is giving me some performance issues, so I'm planning on upgrading it to Raspberry Pi 4.

The thing is that I have already some stuff configured on my Pi 3 that would be a bit of a pain to re-configure on the Pi 4

Can I directly plug the SD card from the Pi3 on the new Pi4 and expect it to work out of the box? Or does it require something extra to make it work?

Comment: You can't do that without completely upgrading the SDcard. If the card has NOOBS, forget it there's too much pain to upgrade it. If it's plain Raspian or plain RaspiOS the `sudo apt update; sudo apt dist-upgrade -y` should get it bootable on a RPi4. But, to be honest, writing a fresh new SDCard will be several orders of magnitude easier.

Comment: @Dougie Thanks for the suggestion! But I've done quite a few things and settings on that Raspberry, and running a few commands to get my SD up and running on my RPi4 is not that much of a problem.

Comment: @Dougie Just to add, I ran those commands and it didn't update anything so I guessed that everything was up to date so I plugged the SD into the new RPi4 and it just worked out of the box wihout anything else. Super neat :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you are using the latest Raspberry Pi OS, fully updated.

It will work in a Pi4.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! I wasn't sure because other questions on this site pointed out that they were using old versions of Raspbian and with those there was no compatiblity

Comment: @RabidTunes RPi 4B is supported since version Buster but all versions are only downstream compatible. So Buster will also run on an RPi 3B(+), but Stretch or older versions does not run on RPi 4B.